# scatterplot displaying incorrect points

Tags: python, plot

I have written a function that simulates the spread of an epidemic and am trying to visualize the spread in a scatterplot. The x value is the generation and the y value is the number of people infected that generation. However, when I plot this graph I get something I have never seen before. The plot does not even respond to color scheme changes. Why might this be happening and is there a way to display the data as one would in a conventional scatterplot? This happens for any number of iterations but gets worse with more iterations.

This is what the plot displays currently:
[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCpGc.png)

```
N=np.zeros(1000)
for x in range(99):
  infections = branch()
  list_length=len(infections)
  sumOfElements=0
  for i in range(list_length):
    infectionsum=sumOfElements+infections[i]
    N[x] = infectionsum
  #print(infections)
  genhouse = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
  #s = [3*s**2 for s in infections]
  plt.scatter(genhouse, infections)
  #plt.scatter(x, y, s=area, c=colors, alpha=0.5)
sum = np.sum(N)
print("the average epidemic size is", sum)
plt.title('Infections across Generations')
plt.xlabel('Generation')
plt.ylabel('Number of Infections')
plt.show()
```

I have included the function that simulates the disease below for additional reference.

```
def branch():
  r = .95 #reproduction number
  manygens = 10 #number of generations to simulate
  N=np.zeros(manygens+1) #how many children in each generation
  howmany = [2]
  G=nx.Graph() 
  count = 0 
  G.add_node(1, gen = count) #gen 0
  manynodes = 1 #how many nodes we currently have on the graph
  N[count] = 1 #one child in gen 0
  for g in range(manygens): #run through generations
    thisgen = 0 #counter for infections this generation
    for node, gen in nx.get_node_attributes(G, "gen").items():
      if gen == g: 
        y = scipy.stats.poisson.rvs(mu=r, size=1) #see how many are infected
        if y < 1: #if less than 1 person is infected (no more reproduction from)
         break
        else:
          reset = 0
          while y >= 1:
            G.add_node(manynodes + 1, gen = count + 1) #add the infected node
            G.add_edge(node, manynodes + 1) #connect to parent
            manynodes = manynodes + 1 #increase node counter
            y = y - 1 #each node we add take away 1 from y
            thisgen = thisgen + 1

          count = count + 1
    howmany.append(thisgen)      
  #nx.draw_spring(G) turn this on to show the graph
  howmany.pop(-1)
  #print(howmany)
  return howmany
```

Comment: Are you maybe confusing `sumOfElements` and `infectionsum`? Seems like that is supposed to be a single variable. Also, use `np.sum` to compute the sum of a list. But, that does not affect your plot anyway. Please tell us why you say your plot is wrong. What makes you suspect that? Why do you blame `scatterplot` and not your calculations? Did you verify your algorithm in other ways? Did you intend to plot all 99 data sets on top of each other?

Comment: I have printed everything and verified that the data matches the intended output so I am fairly certain that my calculations are correct. You're right about sumOfElements and infectionsum being the same thing, I'm fairly certain that is vestigial code from earlier attempts, but after combining the problem remains. I do intent to plot the data sets on top of each other and suspect that the issue is with that, but I can't think of a better way to display the data besides a scatterplot. I suspect the plot is wrong because I am unable to control the colors and it is hard to read.

Comment: Why is there a matlab tag on your question? Your code is python only.

Comment: Put each of the scatter plots in a different axes, and then think about what it would look like to overlay them. That might explain to you your result.

Comment: I must have mistakenly selected matlab instead of matplotlib